# URI Java URI Syntax Exception

Tags: java, uri, desktop

I am trying to browse a uri that is more indepth than just the .com domain here's the code. But its claiming there's a syntax exception and when i throw it it still doesn't work.

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.net.URI;
class Gui {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URI GoogleplusURL = new URI("https://plus.google.com//u//0//115793082536946778715//posts");
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(GoogleplusURL);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. The compiler only tells you that that a specific exception is declared, so you either have to catch or throw(s) it. It does not mean that your URI is broken, since the compiler cannot tell you, only running the program can.

Comment: It works for me too. What platform are you using? According to the Desktop API documentation "On some platforms the Desktop API may not be supported; use the isDesktopSupported() method to determine if the current desktop is supported."

Comment: You probably want to use `/` instead of `//` except right after `https:` part.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with your code.

Following format of code will help you understand the issue. Your code can throw two type of exception

1. URISyntaxException  -- When you use invalid url syntax
    Example: replace your url with https://plus.google.com/u/0/115793082536946778715/^posts
2. IOException  -- This will occur when url is not valid

```html
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          URI GoogleplusURL;
          try {
           GoogleplusURL = new URI("https://plus.google.com/u/0/115793082536946778715/posts");
           Desktop.getDesktop().browse(GoogleplusURL);
          } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
          }
         }
```

In case you worrying about url is not working ? try to change your url

From: https://plus.google.com//u//0//115793082536946778715//posts
To:  https://plus.google.com/u/0/115793082536946778715/posts